# How to use in-memory database with TypeORM in Nest

Tags: typescript, typeorm, nestjs

I have a Nest server that other services depends on. In order to simplify testing of these other services, I would like to spin up a version of the Nest server that does not use a real database. Instead, it should use an in-memory db, like [mongo-unit](https://github.com/mikhail-angelov/mongo-unit).

My idea would be to have a production main module, and a test main module, where the test module would keep everything the same, but use the in-memory db. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to set this up.

I know that I can use `async` providers, but I don't know how that works with imports, which is what `@nestjs/typeorm` exposes:

```
// app.module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ...
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mongodb',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 27017,
      database: 'production',
      entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    ...
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

It needs to be async, because mongo-unit returns a promise with the URL that it listens to. So I need to spin up mongo-unit, before I can initialize TypeORM. I imagine something like this:

```
// app.test.module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import * as mongoUnit from 'mongo-unit';

@Module({})
export class AppModule {
  static async forRoot() {
    const dbUrl = new URL(await mongoUnit.start());
    return {
      imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
          type: 'mongodb',
          host: dbUrl.host,
          port: dbUrl.port,
          database: 'test',
          entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
          synchronize: true,
        }),
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

How can I swap out the database, if it is asynchronously started?
(If there is another approach to this problem than two separate modules, then please tell me! :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible using [async dynamic modules](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/800#issuecomment-402709817).

Alternatively, spinning up the mongo-unit in the test and configuring the application to connect to that db works even better, since the test then has control over the db. I'm using this latter approach. (Unfortunately, there are some [issues](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/671) with it.)